# Проблема с flask restfull

Tags: python, rest, flask, pycharm

Пишу API используя flask_restful:

```
from flask import Flask, send_file, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Test(Resource):
    def get(self):
            return jsonify({"ab":"cd"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
  
    api.add_resource(Test, "/test")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

При попытке сделать запрос браузер выдаёт ошибку 404. В консоль запрос приходит:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021 09:56:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021 09:56:07] "GET /picture/10dc8e1e-cfc5-4c69-86a7-7b27620f3dd3.jpg?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021 09:56:07] "GET /picture/10dc8e1e-cfc5-4c69-86a7-7b27620f3dd3.jpg?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021 09:56:07] "GET /generate?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021 09:56:07] "GET /generate?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021 09:56:08] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021 09:56:09] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Однако он ничего не возвращает. Так же помимо моего запроса там есть еще много посторонних. С чем это может быть связано?

### Правка

Как я понял это какая - то беда c Pycharm. Если явным образом указать порт `app.run(debug=True, host="localhost", port=122)` то программа запускается через 5000 порт

```
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Если запускать через консоль, то все работает нормально и на запросы отвечает

Comment: Если изменение порта игнорируется, значит вы, вероятно, запускаете не тот файл

Comment: Я запускаю его через пкм по коду -> RUN